# Representation of derivative by alinear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\phi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be the map $\phi(x,y)=z$  where $z=x+iy$.Let $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be the function that is $f(z)=z^2$and  $F=\phi^{-1}f\phi $..

Represent the derivative of $F$ at $(x,y)$ by a linear transformation.

Can someone please help me to understand what is being asked in the problem i.e what I will hve to find here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi(x,y) = x+iy$, so $f(\phi(x,y)) = (x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2 xy i$.

All $\phi^{-1}$ does is to map $x+iy$ to $(x,y)$, so we have
$F(x,y) = \phi^{-1}(f(\phi(x,y))) = (x^2-y^2, 2 xy)^T$.

Now differentiate $F$. The resulting matrix is the linear transformation.

I am guessing that the problem is trying to show the connection to 
the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: Wow, 3 minutes, that's impressive ;)

Comment: @mathreadler: Improving my typing skills :-).

Comment: yes I got my answer